# Hide address and status bar in Webview during IOS Google SignIn

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, google-signin

I am using Google SignIn framework to allow for logging into the application. Everything is fine except that the actual login/credential input view looks pretty lame and obviously a uiwebview, as showed on the attached image [image]

Is there a way to hide address and status bar in Webview during IOS Google SignIn

I amusing Swift but if you have a solution in ObjC it is fine too.

Comment: What kind of web view are you using? `UIWebVIew` doesn't have a address bar unless you put it in yourself. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I am not using explicitly any web view it is Google's framework which loads it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that is possible, plus that is not a UIWebView is SFSafariViewController.